# Is there a word for "pronounced with profundity?"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am in need of a word (in English or otherwise) that specifically describes the way in which someone pronounces something as profound? I mean profundity coming solely from *how* something is said, irrespective of what is actually said.  Three examples of exactly what I mean include:

"Ridged chips":
https://youtu.be/MsXGgZJN-IM?t=52

"I love Abba":
https://youtu.be/5zabCBnUHLA?t=47

"You and he were... buddies, weren't you":
https://youtu.be/GjOEcoMy2fI

In each of these quotes there is nothing inherently remarkable, yet they stand out simply by the nature of how they are articulated. Does anyone know a word for this?

Comment: Is the answer you seek something like *spoken with a voice like Barry White's* or *basso profoundo*?  I mean, is it the sound or the seriousness you are trying to express? I ask because I have no intention to follow those URLs into the cesspit that is the Internet beyond a few islands of safety.

Comment: In my previous comment I blame autocorrection for *profoundo* where I intended to write *profondo*.

Comment: In English, we say or state things. We don't pronounce them in that sense. Though we do make pronouncements...

Comment: Do you want an adjective, an agent noun, an abstract noun, an adverb, or a verb? Are you talking about a voice like Morgan Freeman or Don LaFontaine (the "In a world..." trailer guy)?

Comment: *subext* maybe? https://www.stagemilk.com/what-is-subtext-in-acting/

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what exact meaning you're going for, but one possibility matching the title:

- [**portentously**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/portentously#English) — in an ominous or pompous manner, relating to something of momentous or ominous significance, prophetic, or puffed up with vanity.

However, the clips you link to aren't as strong as that. Perhaps just:

- [**emphatically**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/emphatically) — with emphasis, in a forceful manner, with conviction.

Comment: +1 for portentously

Comment: Ahh, don't you just love the self-descriptive words like *portentously*.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark You can't beat _sesquipedalian_ for self-description.

Comment: @user888379 There are lots of good autological words, though — _adjectival_, _awkwardful_, _clear_, _cutesy_, _dactylic_, _fifteen-lettered_, _grandiloquent_, _inflected_, _Latinate_, _mispeled_, _nasal_, _plosive_, _polysyllabic_, _recherché_, _sibilant_, _staccato_, _supererogatory_, _terse_…

Comment: @gidds +1 for deploying autological. 1st step on the road to Russell's Paradox.